# Log4j can't write to log file

Tags: java, eclipse, log4j, tomcat7

Log4j can't find a log file in the webapp folder:
Below its configuration file:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, STDOUT, FILE

log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=adminservtool.log
log4j.appender.FILE.MaxFileSize=16MB
log4j.appender.FILE.MaxBackupIndex=256
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=[%d{dd.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss.SSS}] %5p [%t] - %m%n

log4j.appender.STDOUT=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.STDOUT.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.STDOUT.layout.conversionPattern=[%d{dd.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss.SSS}] %5p [%t] - %m%n
log4j.appender.STDOUT.Encoding=UTF-8
```

Project is deployed at `W:\Media\Projects\Eclipse projects\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\my_project_name`.
Maybe I can't get a something but seems Log4j must create it automatically. But it prints error log:

```
log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: adminservtool.log (Отказано в доступе) //Access denied
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:294)
    at org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender.setFile(RollingFileAppender.java:207)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.activateOptions(FileAppender.java:165)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:307)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:172)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:104)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:842)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:768)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configureRootCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:648)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:514)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:580)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:526)
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:127)
    at org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:104)
    at com.skat.smev.conviction.util.Config.<clinit>(Config.java:12)
    at com.skat.smev.conviction.listener.SmevResultListener.initialize(SmevResultListener.java:26)
    at com.skat.smev.conviction.listener.SmevResultListener.<init>(SmevResultListener.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:114)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5026)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5633)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1694)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1684)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Where should I create my log file then?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your log file path is not setup properly and/or you don't have an acess to it.
I suggest to point it to some writable location